# A Catalog of Special Plane Curves Book - Dennis

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

Can anyone recommend a book similar to above?

The idea is to sketch out the locus of the various curves and derive their parametric forms which I enjoy and in the process learn about their properties etc

Thanks

Comment: "Book of Curves" by H. Lockwood, but Dennis is better imo.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha's very useful for plotting them, or in your case, checking them. The parametric plotting is excellent: ParametricPlot[{x=sin(t)^2, y=(cos2t)^2}, {t, 0, pi}] : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot%5B%7Bx%3Dsin%28t%29%5E2%2C+y%3D%28cos2t%29%5E2%7D%2C+%7Bt%2C+0%2C+pi%7D%5D

Comment: Yes indeed but the idea was that I would like to derive the equations by hand from the sketches

Comment: https://2dcurves.com/